# mvc with ajax post

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

i have a form which includes list of records. When user clicks edit image on table modal div will show to him. i get this modal div with ajax. Now after changing some fields i am posting it via ajax. I watched to firebug. it sends parameter. But when i debug code in VS method calls but no parameter has been send. i have done it before in other pages. but now i can not. What problem can be here in my code?

C# Code here

```
 [HttpPost]
 //[Authorize(Roles = "Operator")]
 public ActionResult EditRow(string Name, string SecondName)
 {          
    //code goes here
    return Content("Saved");
 }
```

jquery ajax code is here

```
  $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
       url: 'EditRow',
       data: { Name: "php", SecondName: "MVC" },
       dataType: 'html',
       success: function (response) {
        //some code goes here
       }
      });
```

Comment: Suspect the problem is the contentType, try removing it.

Comment: yes you are right but why? i have done it with ContentType before. All worked for me. But minute I remember. ContentType problem was when i have wrote sample code in jsp page. but in mvc it worked always

Comment: Thank you,Paul. you helped me too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to simplify your Ajax call to:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'EditRow',
    data: { Name: "php", SecondName: "MVC" },
    success: function (response) {
        //some code goes here
    }
});
```

If this doesn't work there must be something else in your code that makes your code invalid. Maybe some base controller action filters you forgot to put there or some custom model binders or some other global registration.

### Sending complex JSON to server

If you'd like to send complex JSON using the same technique, you can read [my blog post](http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2010/12/sending-complex-json-objects-to-aspnet.html) and use the simple plugin that will make it possible to send complex JSON objects to Asp.net MVC controller action.

Comment: yes it worked without contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' and  dataType: 'html', arguments. why?

Comment: Check jQuery code. If you set certain content types it tends to adjust data accordingly.

Comment: The thing is that this particular object you're sending is only single-level JSON object which will be correctly encoded. If your object would be more complex... Check my edited answer.

Comment: yes without ContentType it worked. I will search why it was happen later. Tahnks for help